# Removing certain lines in textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, split, streamreader, multiline

I have a proxy list, that is like IP:PORT, and what I need to do is remove all the proxies with port numbers of 8080, 80, 431, and 13. I've tried to use a StreamReader to do this, but to no avail, any help guys? Thank you.

My code efforts:

```
    Using reader As New StreamReader(o.FileName())
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
            Dim X As String = line.Contains("8080")
            For Each X In NsTextBox1.Text
                NsTextBox1.Text = NsTextBox1.Text + X
                Exit While
            Next
        End While
    End Using
```

Comment: **I've tried to use a StreamReader to do this** Please share your efforts!!

Comment: Using reader As New StreamReader(o.FileName())
            While Not reader.EndOfStream
                Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
                Dim X As String = line.Contains("8080")
                For Each X In NsTextBox1.Text
                    NsTextBox1.Text = NsTextBox1.Text + X
                    Exit While
                Next
            End While
        End Using

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code there. It will help others also to understand your question!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently wrote something that should do the trick nicely, if the proxy list contains 1 IP per line without white space at the end that is.
While not the most optimized code it works pretty well, here's some output of it parsing a list of about 6000 proxies.

[image: Output]

You'd use it as such.

```
IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\ProxyOut.txt", ParseProxyList(IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\ProxyIn.txt"), 8080, 80, 431, 13))
```

EDIT: oh i just read it was for a textbox, usage should not be that different

```
TextBoxOut.Text = ParseProxyList(TextBoxIn.Text, 8080, 80, 431, 13))
```

And the Function itself:

```
Private Function ParseProxyList(ByVal list As String, ParamArray ports() As Integer)
    Dim splitList() As String = list.Split(vbCrLf)
    Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    Dim outputLinesCount As Integer = 0
    For Each line As String In splitList
        Dim bContainsPort As Boolean = False
        For Each port As Integer In ports
            If line.EndsWith(":" & port.ToString) Then
                bContainsPort = True
            End If
        Next
        If bContainsPort = False Then
            sb.AppendLine(line)
            outputLinesCount += 1
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox(splitList.Count.ToString & "->" & outputLinesCount.ToString & " (" & (splitList.Count - outputLinesCount) & " Removed)")
    Return sb.ToString
End Function
```

Comment: @user2579399 .. you must mark this as the answer ! .. it helped you isn't it ? .. make a green tick below downvote sign ..